# $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then $\int_{x}^{x+h}\frac{|f(t)-f(x)|}{h}dt\to 0$ if $h\to 0$ for almost all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to prove if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then $\int_{x}^{x+h}\frac{|f(t)-f(x)|}{h}dt\to 0$ if $h\to 0$ for almost all $x$ but I am not sure.

Attempt - Let $\phi(x)=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{|f(t)-f(y)|}{h}dt$. So $\int_{x}^{x+h}\frac{|f(t)-f(x)|}{h}dt=\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)\to h\phi'(x)=|f(t)-f(y)|\to0$ because $t\to y$ as $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you wrote is: if $f$ is not continuous, $\phi$ is not guaranteed o be derivable with derivative $f$ (sad).

What you can do:
$$
\int_x^{x+h} \frac{|f(t) - f(x)|}{h} dt
= \int_0^1 {|f(x + \theta h) - f(x)|} d\theta
$$

and now use the dominated convergence theorem.